# Implication of vacuous truth on the space of possible statements

Tags: logic

Considering the concept of vacuous truth, I thought of the following argument:

Say the following proposition is true:
$$
\forall{y}\left[\forall{x}\left[x\in{y}\rightarrow \varphi(x)\right]\rightarrow\psi(y)\right]
$$
Then there exists no predicate $\tau$ such that:
$$
\forall{y}\left[\forall{x}\left[x\in{y}\rightarrow \tau(x)\right]\rightarrow\neg\,\psi(y)\right]
$$
For otherwise, we would have: $ \neg\,\psi(\emptyset) \land \psi(\emptyset)$.

Is the above argument correct? If so, does it have a name?

Comment: A consequence of the first line is $\psi(\varnothing)$, and a consequence of the second proposition is $\neg \psi(\varnothing)$, so your reasoning is correct.  But why would this be interesting enough to have a name?  By the way "true in ZFC" is not a good way to state something.  You may say "true" or "true in a certain model" or "provable in ZFC"

Comment: @GEdgar Don't know if the above has any interesting applications. But it does place (what I consider) an interesting limitation on the existence of certain types of predicates (i.e. predicates such as $\tau$).

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser - This is a limitation if you show that such a predicate $\psi$ does exist. If $\psi$ were contradictory, you would be talking about nothing...

Answer (score 1):

*Long comment*

A similar issue we have using the definition of the *empty set* :

> $\lnot \exists x (x \in \emptyset)$

we have, by [Ex Falso Quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) tautological schema : $\lnot \mathcal P \to (\mathcal P \to \mathcal Q)$, that :

> $\mathsf {ZF} \vdash \exists x (x \in \emptyset) \to \varphi$,

with a formula $\varphi$ whatever.

So, in conclusion, if $\mathsf {ZF}$ is consistent, we cannot have :

> $\mathsf {ZF} \vdash ∀y[\exists x(x∈y) → φ] → ψ$

and :

> $\mathsf {ZF} \vdash ∀y[\exists x(x∈y) → \tau] → \lnot ψ.$

But this is true in general for every theorem $\text {T}$ of $\mathsf {ZF}$ : if the theory is consistent, we cannot have both : $\mathsf {ZF} \vdash \text {T} \to ψ$ and $\mathsf {ZF} \vdash \text {T} \to \lnot ψ$.